# Confusion about the number of partitions after a group by

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, shuffle

How spark partitions the data after applying the groupby transformation while using the spark sql. Is it equal to `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` or the number of groups which can be created by the data. Below is the sample code and data.

```
var studentDF = createStudentDF()       //student: <Id, Name, Department>
studentDF.registerTempTable("students")
x = sqlContext.sql("select depid, count(*) from students group by depid")
x.rdd.count
```

Since the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is 200 by default, I was expecting 200 partitions but there were only 3 deps when run on the below data.

```
ID NAME DEPID
1  ABC  1  
2  DEF  1  
3  GHI  2  
4  JKL  2  
5  MNO  3
```

Is it so that the spark eliminates the empty partitions after the operation completes or I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: @user6910411 please take a look at the complete question

Comment: OK, let's be more explicit :) `x.rdd.count` doesn't check the number of partitions. Please check the linked thread to learn how to properly check the number of partitions.